# What should be proper definition of a polyhedron(not necessarily convex)?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, manifolds, definition, polyhedra

I have searched for a rigorous definition of a polyhedron in Euclidean $3$-space and found that (on wikipedia)  it is quite difficult to formulate general definition as Euler,  Cauchy etc.  failed to do so. 
Now I have a definition in my mind but could anybody please point out where is the flaw?

**Definition** : A set *E* will be called a polyhedron in $3$-space if followings hold:

1. It is compact,  locally flat (embedded  $C^0$)  $3$-submanifold with boundary.
2. Its boundary consists of finitely many polygons.

Any help will be appreciated.

P. S.  I want a definition that will work for the proof of Dehn-Sydler Theorem.

Comment: Isn't "convex hull of a finite set of non-coplanar points" easier?

Comment: @lord  That will be a convex polyhedron.  I want a definition for concave as well.  Actually for Dehn-Sydler thm one should want to have a solid definition of arbitrary polyhedron.

Comment: Although I have no good knowledge on this, it seems to me that what you have in your mind is similar to [*simplicial complex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex).

Comment: @lee simplicial complex is much more general notion.

Comment: Could you start with convex polyhedra and then look at set differences in some way?

Comment: You need to include connected as part of the definition.  Otherwise you could have several polyhedra.

Comment: @herb that's no problem.  A polyhedron might have finitely many components.

Comment: @cameron that's a good idea but there seems to be several plausible definitions but I want a definition that will work for Dehn-Sydler theorem.

Comment: You should include that theorem in the body of the post.

Comment: If you haven't seen it, I recommend the note ["Are your polyhedra the same as my polyhedra?' (PDF)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6ae8/57764309574ef66870ebdbab0788c95d5e20.pdf) by Branko Grünbaum. Grünbaum is considered quite authoritative in the field of combinatorial geometry.

Comment: @Blue thank you.